# why the value of time stamps in JavaScript is different with php time()

Tags: php, sql

why i have different result between PHP time() and JavaScript?!

for example :

my timestamps value in SQL database is `"1779473235"` and the result for this timestamps with JavaScript function is:

```
<script>    

new Date(1779473235*1000).toLocaleString(); //result is "5/22/2026, 10:37:15 PM"

<script>
```

But when i try to covert same date to timestamps with JavaScript code i have difference value:

```
<script>    
    new Date( '5/22/2026' ).getTime() / 1000;  //result is "1776799800"
</script>
```

as you see `1779473235 != 1776799800`  so why?
how i can make fix this problem?

Comment: `1779473235` is not a "timestamp" in SQL. That's plain integer

Comment: Well, `"5/22/2026, 10:37:15 PM"` and `'5/22/2026'` is not the same timestamp either.

Comment: `new Date('5/22/2026').getTime()` gives me `1779400800000`, a very different timestamp. `m/d/Y` notation is very VERY ambiguous, and browsers will interpret it differently and or with bugs, depending on what your browser and locale is. That's your main issue: don't rely on Javascript to parse ambiguous date formats correctly.